# Angular on IE 11 intranet - programmatically disable Compatibility View

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, intranet, polyfills

I'm running an `Angular 6` app on company `intranet` via `IE11`. My app compiles to `ES5` according to `tscnfig.json`. I've uncommented and installed all of the IE compatibility lines in `polyfills.js`. I've also added the suggested meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` just below my `<head>` tag.

None of this had had the intended behavior of programmatically disabling IE's default Compatibility View settings. By default, IE11 `displays intranet sites in Compatibility View`, which breaks Angular. The only solution I've been able to find is having every one of our users go into their IE's `Compatibility View Settings` and uncheck this box:

[image]

This is less than desirable. Is there something else I can try? In some places I've read that there's no workaround for this - and in others, I've read the `IE=Edge` meta tag is the solution - but I've found the meta tag fix to be fake news...that I can tell you.

Comment: it also matters where you put the tag... did you put the meta tag right below the head tag?

Comment: the best you can is displaying a message "IE is not supported, use any normal browser"

Comment: If your in a domain environment you can configure that setting centrally via a GPO template.

Comment: @pixelbits - yes I did.

Comment: do you have <!doctype html>?

Comment: @AlexK. thanks for that. I wouldn't want to do that company-wide - is there typically a way to do this only for a specified set/group of users, or perhaps for every user accessing a particular server? I've never tried this before and will need to open a ticket w/ a network admin.

Comment: we had a similar issue in our corporate environment, we solved it with the meta tag.  I don't believe there was an explicit policy forcing compatibility mode if the meta tag is set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went back and looked closer at my index.html file. The only changes I made was that we had a duplicate meta tag that was commented out, and some extra spacing between our Edge meta tag's attributes and the `/>` at the end.

I erased all of these and now the app works regardless of the settings. I tried to play around with deleting some spaces but not others, or not deleting the commented code vs deleting it - the change from the app working to not working at that point seemed random and didn't really add up (server lag?) - so I couldn't pinpoint the cause. But I do know that once I removed all of the excess spacing and the commented out meta, it works - despite me thinking this wouldn't matter.

Made sure I cleared cache, etc before testing each time, and had my team mates try on their machine. I hope this solved the issue and it's not more random than that. If it breaks again, I'll update this thread, but for now its working. Thanks to all who commented.